# How to Assign the value to Main /Parent Structure in a Nested Structure?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, structure

Hi I have writen an Nested Structure in C# . Find the code snippet below:

```
public struct SMB_MESSAGE
        {

            #region SMB Parameter
            public struct SMB_PARAMETERS
            {
                public byte WordCount;
                public ushort[] Words;
            }
            #endregion

            #region SMB Data
            public struct SMB_DATA
            {
                public ushort ByteCount;
                public struct Bytes
                {
                    public ushort BufferFormat;
                    public byte[] Name;
                }
            }
            #endregion

        }
```

Now While I assign the Value to the the Inner structure as below:

```
SMB_MESSAGE SMBMESSAGE;

SMB_MESSAGE.SMB_PARAMETERS SMBPARAMETER;
SMBPARAMETER.WordCount=12;
SMBPARAMETER.Words=null;

SMB_MESSAGE.SMB_DATA SMBDATA;
SMBDATA.ByteCount=byteCount;

SMB_MESSAGE.SMB_DATA.Bytes bytes;
bytes.BufferFormat=bFormat;
bytes.Name=name;
```

Now When I look into the value of SMBMESSAGE while debugging it shows `NameSpace.Form1.SMB_MESSAGE` and no values inside it. I can't also see a way to asign the values to `SMBMESSAGE` .
If we can not assign values , then Why do we need to use nested structures?

Comment: Your `struct` names are horrible.

Comment: @SLaks, I would like to know why?

Comment: All-caps should never be used in C#.  Instead, you should name them something like `Message`, `MessageParameter`, `MessageData`, and `DataBytes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two inner structs are nested *types*, not instance members.
Nested types have no effect on instances of the parent types; they are a purely organizational concept (except that they can access the parent type's private members)

Therefore, your `SMB_MESSAGE` struct doesn't actually have any instance members.

You need to make four normal structs, then make two properties in `SMB_MESSAGE` holding the other two structures.

For example:

```
public struct SMB_MESSAGE {
    public SMB_PARAMETERS Parameters;
    public SMB_DATA Data;

}
public struct SMB_PARAMETERS
{
    public byte WordCount;
    public ushort[] Words;
}

public struct SMB_DATA
{
    public ushort ByteCount;
    public Bytes Bytes;
}
public struct Bytes
{
    public ushort BufferFormat;
    public byte[] Name;
}
```

Comment: Got It, Just wondering then Why any one Will use nested structure. For which purpose they can be used?